# Harish-Chandra's submersive principle on closed subsets

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, p-adic-number-theory, schwartz-space

I asked the same question here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247669/harish-chandras-submersive-principle-on-closed-subsets ,
but did not get an answer. I want to see if I will have some luck in this site.

Harish-Chandra's submersion principle says the following. Let $X,Y$ be two manifolds of dimensions $m$ and $n$ respectively. Let $\pi: X\rightarrow Y$ be a surjective smooth map which is submersive everywhere. Let $\omega_X,\omega_Y$ be two differential forms on $X$ and $Y$ respectively of degree $m$ and $n$. Then for every $\alpha\in C_c^\infty(X)$, there exists a unique function $F_\alpha\in C_c^\infty(Y)$ such that 
$$\int_X \alpha(x) \phi(\pi(x))d\omega_X =\int_Y F_\alpha(y)\phi(y)d\omega_Y$$
for all $\phi\in C_c^\infty(Y)$.

[Reference: Harish-Chandra, $\textit{Invariant distributions on Lie Algebras}$, American Journal of Math, $\textbf{86}$(1964),271-309,

The p-adic version can be found in

Harish-Chandra, Notes by G.van Dijk, $\textit{Harmonic Analysis on reductive p-adic groups}$, Lecture Notes in Math, $\textbf{162}$, p.48-49.]

Since the defining property of $F_\alpha$ is given by an integral, it seems very hard to detect values of $F_\alpha$ on closed subsets of $Y$. For example, we consider the following situation. Suppose that $X=X_1\times X_2$, and we identify $X_1$ with $X_1\times 0$, where $0\in X_2$ is a fixed point. Let $\pi, Y$ be as in the first paragraph. If we know 
$$\int_{X_1}\alpha(x_1)\phi(\pi(x_1))d\omega_{X_1}=0$$
for all $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\pi(X_1))$ and $\pi^{-1}(Y_1)\subset X_1$, can we conclude that the restriction of $F_\alpha$ to the closed set $\pi(X_1)$ is zero?

If the above is wrong, let us consider a weaker form of the above problem. Given $\beta\in C_c^\infty(X_1)$, if 
$$\int_{X_1}\beta(x_1)\phi(\pi(x_1))dx_1=0,$$
for all $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\pi(X_1))$, could we find a function $\alpha\in C_c^\infty(X)$ such that $\alpha|_{X_1}=\beta$ and $F_\alpha|_{\pi(X_1)}=0$?

A slightly different way to formulate this question is as follows. Denote $Y_1=\pi(X_1)$. Thus $\pi|_{X_1}:X_1\rightarrow Y_1$ is also submersive (is this true?). Thus Harish-Chandra's submersion principle gives a map $\beta\mapsto F_\beta$ from $C_c^\infty(X_1)$ to $C_c^\infty(Y_1)$ which satisfies 
$$\int_{X_1}\beta(x_1)\phi(\pi(x_1))d\omega_{X_1}=\int_{Y_1}F_\beta(y)\phi(y)d\omega_{Y_1}$$
for all $\phi\in C_c^\infty(Y_1)$. Is there any chance to make the following diagram commutative(at least in the p-adic case)?
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    C_c^\infty(X) @>{HC}>> C_c^\infty(Y)\\
    @V res V V @VV res V\\
    C_c^\infty(X_1) @>>HC> C_c^\infty(Y_1)
\end{CD}
where the horizontal arrows are Harish-Chandra decent, and the vertical arrows are restrictions. In the p-adic case, the restrictions are surjective.

Comment: It looks like $F_{\alpha}(y)=\int_{\pi^{-1}(y)}\alpha(x')d\tilde{\omega}_{\pi^{-1}(y)}W_{\pi}$, where $d\tilde{\omega}_{\pi^{-1}(y)}$ is the restriction of $d\omega_{X}$ to the fibre and $W_{\pi}$ is a weight. I have calculated, for my personal use, these kind of integrals over fibres and I can post the formula here if you want. Since you ask for vanishing, we don't care of $W_{\pi}>0$, and any test for $F_{\alpha}(y)=0$ should verify what does it happen over the fibre $\pi^{-1}(y)$. As I see, if $\pi^{-1}(y)\not\subset X_1$, then your test doesn't work. Good luck!

Comment: Take the projection from $\pi:\mathbb{R}^{3}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,0,0)$. Take $X_1=\{(0,y,z)\}$, then $\pi_{X_1}$ is not submersive. But in just this case, it seems that your test works! Not sure. (In my previous comment, the weight goes inside the integral)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you kindly post your formula?

Comment: @user90189 
I am also very interested how you got your first formula.

Answer (score 2):

Qing Zhang, I got the formula because I need to calculate constantly convolutions of measures supported on surfaces, see also Hormander, "The analysis of linear partial differential operators", V. I, Thm. 6.1.2.

I will kept the discussion rather sketchy. Since we are working on manifolds, we can use a partition of unity and deal with the euclidian case; furthermore, to keep this post simple, I assume that $d\omega_X=dx$ and $d\omega_y=dy$, but the general case requires to add a weight.

Given a submersion $\pi:\mathbb{R}^{m}\to\mathbb{R}^n$, for $m\ge n$, we are asked about 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{m}}\alpha(x)\phi(\pi(x))\,dx.
$$
We want to make a change of variables and to integrate instead over $\mathbb{R}^n$, but how to do that, if in general $\pi$ is not a diffeomorphism? Notice that $\mathbb{R}^m$ is foliated by the fibers of $\pi$, namely, by $\pi^{-1}(y)$, which are manifolds of codimension $n$.

Make a partition of $\mathbb{R}^n$ into small cubes $Q_{\delta}$, as in the Riemann integral, then the inverse image $\pi^{-1}(Q_{\delta})$ looks like a neighbourhood of $\pi^{-1}(y)$, for $y$ the center of $Q_{\delta}$, with variable width, depending on $d\pi$ for each point over the fiber.

Hence, we can write
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{m}}\alpha(x)\phi(\pi(x))\,dx &= \sum_{y}\int_{\pi^{-1}(Q_{\delta})}\alpha(x)\phi(\pi(x))\,dx,\\
&\sim \sum_{y}\phi(y)\big[\int_{\pi^{-1}(y)}\alpha(x)W_{\pi}\,dS\big]\delta^{n}, \\
&\sim \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\big[\int_{\pi^{-1}(y)}\alpha(x)W_{\pi}\,dS]\phi(y)\,dy,
\end{align}
where the term $W_{\pi}$ takes into account the variability of the width of the neighbourhood along the fibre and $dS$ is the induced measure, from the euclidian metric, on the fibre. We have that $W_{\pi}=|\det(\langle\nabla\pi_i,\nabla\pi_j\rangle)|^{-1/2}$, for $\pi=(\pi_1,\dots, \pi_n)$.

The previous discussion can be made into a rigorous proof, but this is, admitely, not the best way and I only wanted to motivate. A proof can go by reducing to a neighborhood of each point and then to complete $\pi$ with the variables, say, $x_{n+1},\ldots,x_{m}$, so that we have a diffeomorphism, then we apply the classical change of variables and make up the formula to her final look.

If there is any issue, I would receive any criticism.

Comment: It will be great if you have a published version. I need some kind results like this in the p-adic case. Anyway, I will try to understand your argument. Thank you very much.

Comment: In my work, I only care about the Euclidean case, but now I realize that for general manifolds it is not so straightforward. Notice that I used the Euclidean structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to define the induced measure on $\pi^{-1}(y)$, but how do I define the restriction of $d\omega_X$ in a general manifold to a submanifold? By the way, for paracompact manifold, you can always define a metric and use it, but it'd be better if the metric is compatible with $d\omega_X$. The philosphy is always the same, to work over the fibre, however an invariant formula could be harder to obtain.

Comment: If we assume your formula and $\pi^{-1}(Y_1)\subset X_1$, it seems that $\int_{X_1} \alpha(x_1)\phi(\pi(x_1))dx_1=0,\forall \phi\in S(Y_1)$ implies that $F_\alpha|_{Y_1}=0$. The situation is quite similar to the example you took (the projection $\textbf{R}^3\rightarrow \textbf{R}$). Since I am working on p-adic case, I have trouble to make your argument rigorous and I am wondering if there is a simpler and more direct proof.

Comment: Zhang, I have outlined two proofs in my answer: a motivated long proof, and a less motivated short proof. I'm willing to help you, but I don't know if this page is the best way of doing that. You can contact me to my e-mail (see my profile). My knowledge of p-adic analysis is poor, so I cannot do much, but as a first advice, you'd work not with manifolds, but with p-adic fields and try to exploit as much structure you have. Use the Haar measure, it is sufficient, and begin with the case when the image has dimension one. Do you really need a formula, or simply qualitative properties of $F$?

Comment: Recall, I'm using the metric structure of the euclidean space, because I need to measure the width of the "fibres" (this is the term $W_{\pi}$).